# Issue with .zip for iterable (rxJava)

Tags: android, rx-java

I have code that with four Observable. I apply the `Observable.zip` to them:

```
Observable<Currencies> usd = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies();
    Observable<Currencies> rub = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies("RUB");
    Observable<Currencies> eur = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies("EUR");
    Observable<Currencies> btc = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies("BTC");

    List<Observable<Currencies>> singles = new ArrayList<>();
    singles.add(usd);
    singles.add(rub);
    singles.add(eur);
    singles.add(btc);

    Observable<Currencies> c = Observable.zip(singles, new Function<Currencies[], Currencies>() {
                @Override
                public Currencies apply(@NotNull Currencies[] objects) throws Exception {
                    return ramming(objects);
                }
            });
```

But i got error:

[image]

The message says that a method with such a signature was not found (maybe i not right), but i go to declaration and see that the signature, sort of like, is suitable.

```
 public static <T, R> Observable<R> zip
 (Iterable<? extends ObservableSource<? extends T>> sources,
 Function<? super Object[], ? extends R> zipper)
```

What i does wrong?

P.S: i thing this bug [RxJava2Iterableisbroken](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4524)

Comment: what's the point of using Flowable when all your sources are Single

Comment: @prathamkesarkar While I was doing this, I went into the rx library. 
I am learning. I do not quite understand how it works. Concat for Single, for example, return Flowable

Comment: It's not a bug. You need a `Function<? super Object[]` because of the generics limitation of Java. This is also explained in [the Javadocs of zips](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug. You need a `Function<? super Object[]` because of the generics limitation of Java. This is also explained in [the Javadocs of zips](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-).

```
Observable<Currencies> usd = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies();
Observable<Currencies> rub = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies("RUB");
Observable<Currencies> eur = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies("EUR");
Observable<Currencies> btc = CoinMarket.getMarketApi().getCurrencies("BTC");

List<Observable<Currencies>> singles = new ArrayList<>();
singles.add(usd);
singles.add(rub);
singles.add(eur);
singles.add(btc);

Observable<Currencies> c = Observable.zip(singles, new Function<Object[], Currencies>() {
            @Override
            public Currencies apply(@NotNull Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                Currencies[] currencies = new Currencies[objects.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                     currencies[i] = (Currencies)objects[i];
                }
                return ramming(currencies);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Flowable and Single are two different entities in RxJava. Flowable implements Publisher, where as Single implements SingleSource. When you are trying to use zip operator, it expects array list of objects which implements Publisher and hence the error.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing with Observable. Same problem

Comment: Did you try  `Observable.zip` operator? because this works.
`Observable<String> usd = new io.reactivex.Observable<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super String> observer) {

            }
        };
        List<Observable<String>> singles = new ArrayList<>();
        singles.add(usd);


        Observable<String> c = Observable.zip(singles, new Function<Object[], String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        });`

Comment: i tried right now. With my type. Same problem. Want to screenshot?

Comment: @IliyaMashin did you try the code which I pasted? using Observable on both the sides? you should update your question and code because it was fundamentally wrong.

Comment: paste your code and noticed that the
'new Function<Currencies[], Currencies>()' not work.

'new Function<Object[], Currencies>()' is work

Comment: not work. i add my functoinality to "apply" method. same error